# Ionic / Capacitor - Is it possible to update the info on the /android directory? ( build.gradle and such)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am currently building an app that, due to client decisions, needs to be build in "two modes" (average users and professionals, for example) and both versions of the app need to be located in separate stores and to be able to deploy simultaneously on the same device (as in, having one version of the app installed shouldn't block the user from installing the other one). This also implies that I'm having to use two different bundle ids (for example, `com.theclient.myapp` and `com.theclient.myprofesionalapp`)

We decided to use a single repo, since 80% or so of the functionality of both versions is identical or common, but I am currently forced to manually change the bundle id and app name any time I'm building an apk/aab - or an .ipa on XCode, for that matter.

Currently whenever I build the app I use a command that, in order, runs the commands `ionic build`, `npx cap sync android` and `npx cap open android`. But said command doesn't seem to rebuild the info on files like the android/app/build.gradle file, even if the info on my root `capacitor.config.json` file has been modified.

My question/s would be:

- Is there a capacitor/ionic command that allows me to refresh or rebuild the information on the /android directory, so that the information present on the .gradle files (such as the /android/app/build.gradle file) is updated?

Ideally I could remove and re-build the android directory any time I need to do this, but this would also delete the assets (splash and icons) I have generated, and possibly other configuration I have changed as well, so I'd rather not resort to this. I am also working on some Node.js commands to change the info present on some of my files, but so far I'm having trouble writing gladle files from a .js Node command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if there is a command to do that but you can acheive this by scripting, 
For example on package.json make a script : node ./file.js. and in file
u check the paths and eniroments in js way.  process.env...ect